# How do I stop my script overwriting?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Below is a batch script that I have put together which copies the content of another folder and pastes it into a new folder that it creates called IC_Transfer.

```
@echo off
@break off
@title IC Transfer

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if not exist "C:\Temp\IC_Transfer" (
    md "C:\Temp\IC_Transfer"
    ROBOCOPY /-y "Q:\Work\Temp\Dan" "C:\Temp\IC_Transfer" /mir 
    if "!errorlevel!" EQU "0" (
        echo Transfer Successful! ) 
        ) else (
        if exist "C:\Temp\IC_Transfer" (
        echo Error Transferring File 
        echo File Already Exists
        :Choice
        set /P c=Would You Like To Overwrite[Y/N]?
            if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto Overwrite
            if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto Stop
        ) )
:Overwrite
    md "C:\Temp\IC_Transfer"
    ROBOCOPY "Q:\Work\Temp\Dan" "C:\Temp\IC_Transfer" /mir 
    if "!errorlevel!" EQU "0" (
    echo Transfer Successful )
    goto End

:Stop
    echo Transfer Cancelled
    goto End

:End 
    pause
    exit

pause
exit
```

The make directory and robocopy functions work as they should by purging the directory, re-creates it and pastes the contents. What I cannot get working is the choice command.

Regardless of whether I choose Y or N it overwrites the file contents.

I'm new to batch scripts so any help would be appreciated

Comment: you know, there *is* a [choicd](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command? (would even be better here than your `set /p` approach). Don't use `:labels` inside a code block. Add `goto :eof` a line before `:Overwrite` to let the script stop there instead of running through. And of course [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) for your `c` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
@break off
@title IC Transfer

setlocal

if not exist "C:\Temp\IC_Transfer" (
    md "C:\Temp\IC_Transfer"
    ROBOCOPY /-y "Q:\Work\Temp\Dan" "C:\Temp\IC_Transfer" /mir
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        echo Transfer Successful!
    ) else (
        echo Error Transferring File
        echo File Already Exists
        call :Choice
    )
)

exit /b

:Choice
    setlocal
    set "c="
    set /P "c=Would You Like To Overwrite[Y/N]? "
    if /I "%c%" == "Y" (
        call :Overwrite
    ) else if /I "%c%" == "N" (
        call :Stop
    ) else call :Stop
exit /b

:Overwrite
    ROBOCOPY "Q:\Work\Temp\Dan" "C:\Temp\IC_Transfer" /mir
    if not errorlevel 1 echo Transfer Successful
    pause
exit /b

:Stop
    echo Transfer Cancelled
    pause
exit /b
```

To fix the issue, labels inside parenthese code blocks is a
bad idea and prone to error. So call the label instead.

I replaced the goto's with calls as `:Choice` will work with a call.
This makes `:End` obsolete.

You used delayed expansion for `errorlevel`, though you could just use
i.e. `if not errorlevel 1` to check if integer value is less than 1.
Delayed expansion has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Labels within `code blocks` (parenthesised series of commands) cause problems (:choice) and are better regarded as illegal.
2. You have invoked `delayedexpansion` and recognised that `errorlevel` may change with the `code block`. Your `set /p` changes the variable `c`, but you are using the parse-time value of `c` (%c%) in your `if` statements, not the run-time value (!c!)
3. What happens should the user enter not-YN? Hint: See the `choice` command - `choice /?` from the prompt.

Since `c` is not set at the start of the code, `"%c%"` will evaluate to `""` which is neither `"Y"` nor `"N"` so the `if`s fail and the code will then proceed to the next statement (:overwrite)

Note that `md` will create a directory or generate an error message if it does not exist, hence

```
md directoryname 2>nul
```

should create the directory and suppress error messages (like 'directory already exists') obviating the test-for-existence gating the `md`.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive criticism. After reading in to what you said and another contributors answer I've got it working and understand why.